# CodeIgniter: can't access $this within function in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and one of my views got pretty large so I moved some of the code in a function in the same file:

```
function html_stuff()
{
    $posts = $this->db->query('select * from posts');
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in
>   object context in /somepath/view.php

Comment: you should be either doing it in a modal or at least a controller ;) you can always create a new CI instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could either pass the function `$this`

```
function html_stuff($ci) {
    $ci->db->query('select * from posts');
}
html_stuff($this);
```

Or use `get_instance()`

```
function html_stuff() {
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $ci->db->query('select * from posts');
}
```

See: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: yeah :) if that solution worked for you, it would be better if you tick the answer :)

Comment: A typo in the answer, `$ci &= get_instance();` should be `$ci = &get_instance();`