# CodeIgniter Error using Memcached inside cURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, memcached

I'm getting an error when trying to use memcached inside a cURl write function inside Codeigniter.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($ch, $str)
                                        {                                                       //print(htmlentities($str)."\n\n");
$ci &= get_instance();
$ci->cache->memcached->save('foo', 'bar', 600);                                              return strlen($str);
});
```

The errors are

```
Message: Undefined variable: ci

Message: Object of class admin_test could not be converted to int
```

Any suggestions?

I tried the advice from this link [CodeIgniter: can't access $this within function in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234159/codeigniter-cant-access-this-within-function-in-view)
and from here:
[Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607550/object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

I can use the $ci syntax to make a database query like this

```
$ci->db->query('SELECT * FROM TABLE');
```

but not with memcached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, not nearly as hard as I thought.

I was using

```
$ci &= get_instance();
```

But what I needed was

```
$ci = get_instance();
```